# Prove that $\exists f\in V^*$ and $w\in W$ s.t. $A(v)=f(v)w\;\forall v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, dual-spaces, dual-maps

> Let $V,W$ be (not necessarily finite-dimensional) vector spaces over the field $\mathbb F$ and $A\in L(V,W)$ s.t. $\operatorname{rank} A=1$. Prove that $\exists f\in V^*$ and $w\in W$ s.t.
>   $$A(v)=f(v)w\;\forall v\in V$$

My attempt:

$$\operatorname{rank} A=1\iff \dim A(V)=1\implies A(V)=\operatorname{span}\lbrace w\rbrace$$

Case : $\dim V=n\lt\infty$

$V^*=L(V,\mathbb F)\implies \dim V^*=\dim V\dim\mathbb F=n$

We could define linear forms $E_{1j}$, or just $e_j^*$,
$$e_j^*(e_k)=\begin{cases}0, &k\ne j\\1,&k=j\end{cases}$$

So, $\left\{e_1^*,e_2^*,\ldots,e_n^*\right\}$ could be a dual basis.
Since $e_j^*$ is linear: $e_j^*\left(\lambda e_j\right)=\lambda e_j^*\left(e_j\right)=\lambda\in\mathbb F$

$\implies\exists f\in V^*$ s.t. $f=e_j\left(\lambda e_k\right)$ and $f(V)=\mathbb F$

But this isn't proof and it doesn't cover an infinite-dimensional $V$.

---

I've seen that for $V,\dim V=\infty,\;\dim V^*=2^{\dim V}$ and considered what I've read [on the intuition behind the dual space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2776841/721644), [transpose of compositions of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987300/721644) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377157/infinite-dimensional-constant-rank-theorem), but we haven't reached that.

I don't believe all those threads are relevant for this particular task, but I' m going to leave them here just in case.

May I ask for advice on solving this task? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that there exists $w \in W$ such that every $A(v)$ is of the form $f(v) w$ for a (necessarily unique) $f(v) \in \mathbb F$.

All you need to show is that $f : V \to \mathbb F$ is a linear map, which follows from the linearity of $A$. (Check this!)